# C# best way to call .ToString() on an object

Tags: c#, url-rewriting

How would you write a call to the .ToString() method on an object of type object that can be null. I currently do the following, but it's pretty long :

```
  myobject == null ? null : myobject.ToString()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way to make the behaviour more encapsulated is to put it in an extension method:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static string NullSafeToString(this object input)
    {
        return  input == null ? null : input.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then you can call `NullSafeToString` on any object:

```
object myobject = null;
string temp = myobject.NullSafeToString();
```

Comment: So with extension methosd, you can call methods on null references ! Weird but it solve my issue !

Comment: Well as potentially you do not know whether converting null object to null string appropriate in all cases i think it is reasonable to add an overload that takes default value.

Comment: @Duaner: it's not as weird as it looks like; it's just syntactic sugar. The call `myobject.NullSafeToString()` in my sample will be translated by the compiler into `ObjectExtensions.NullSafeToString(myobject)`.

Answer (score 2):

If you use that specific type frequently in this way you could write a method `GetString(object foo)` which will return a string or null. This will save you some typing.
Is there something similar to C++ templates in C#? If yes, you could apply that to the `GetString()` method, too.

Comment: I use it frequetnly but from differnt part of the wall projet, so I would nee a call to something like Tools.GetString(). That be better. But is there a syntax that do not need to call a method ?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you want a null string for a null object? I would think this more likely:

```
myobject == null ? string.Empty : myobject.ToString()
```

That is not directly wrong, but I remember some guideline where functions should accept null and Empty but preferably not return null strings.

Comment: Yep, I need a null when null.